# Opening fail-safe electrical strike door with a spring

Tags: spring, fail-safe

I have a 12V fail-safe electrical strike currently installed and working on a door, but I want it to **open slightly** when it is powered down, but a **spring apparently won't do** as my strikes keep themself locked if they have a constant force acting on them (so after unlocking, you either have to pull the door and the spring pushes it away, or push the door in place and the spring pushes it on you)

The question is: is there a way to open slightly the door with another type of electrical strike or is this kind of *security* on every one of them ? I need it to **stay fail-safe** though.

---

The other options I see are a solenoid pushing the door after the strike is opened, or a magnetic lock with a spring. Are there easier workarounds I didn't thought of ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: what does `open slightly` mean? ... your question has nothing to do with electronics ... it appears to be a mechanics related question

Comment: I am tring to get past that "security" that keeps me from opening this door with a spring. @jsotola that means 5 to 10 cm, enough to see the door is open

Comment: @jsotola is there a stackexchange my question might fit in ? maybe engineering ?

Comment: click the blue icon, that has three horizontal lines, at the top of this page

Comment: You also need to define what "fail-safe" means in your application. Does "safe" mean doors lock (as in a prison) or that doors open (as in a fire escape). [Edit] it into your quesiton - don't bury it in the comments.

Comment: Prisons use fail-secure not fail-safe...

Comment: And they do define the fail-safe. "Want to open when powered down".

Comment: @Passerby: It may depend on which side of the bars you're on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is **"preload"**. Loading the keeper on an electric strike will cause it to bind, preventing the solenoid to release the keeper. Once pressure is released, it's free to move again. It's not really a security feature, but a mechanical problem with the design. It's a minor problem in most cases that's easily overcome by behavior changes, so manufacturers dont put in the time/research/money to engineer a better fix.

There are electric strikes made to work in environments where preload exists (misaligned doors/walls, high air pressure from HVAC, etc). Or you can chose a different type of locking mechanism that does not have this physical problem.

To get the existing one working, you could add an active system, like your own solenoid that will push the door after 1s of power loss.

Comment: That is definitely what i am looking for, i was worried it was a design flaw, but relieved there are strikes that counter this issue, will look into that :D

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a magnetic lock rather than an electric door strike. These are used in many applications such as holding fire doors open until a fire alarm is triggered.

One common use of magnetic locks is holding doors closed in security areas.

The specific advantage of a magnetic lock is that it releases completely upon removal of power.

Comment: There are energise-to-release maglocks too. The coil counters the permanent magnets. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/245575/73158.